# ReactJS - AutoComplete inside AppBar in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am learning ReactJS and I built an `AppBar` and added a `TextField` inside that. It was working perfectly. The following is my code:

```
class Test extends React.Component {  
render() {
    return (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <AppBar
        title={"Benchmarking"}
        iconElementLeft={<IconButton iconClassName="muidocs-icon-custom-github" />}
        iconElementRight={
          <div>
            <TextField
                hintText='this is a sample text'
            />
          </div>
        }
      />

      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

Now I tried to add an `AutoField` in the place of `TextField`, its not throwing any error, but the `AppBar` is not displaying. What might be the problem? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an `AutoComplete` requires the `dataSource` and `onUpdateInput` props so you will have to provide that. Do something like this

```
 state = {
    dataSource: [],
  };

  handleUpdateInput = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: [
        value,
        value + value,
        value + value + value,
      ],
    });
  };
```

Then pass them as props in the `AutoComplete`

```
  <AutoComplete
          hintText="Type anything"
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          onUpdateInput={this.handleUpdateInput}
        />
```

Here is the link to the `AutoComplete` page in `Material-UI` - http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete

Comment: My bad. I dint try with the state parameters. Thanks a lot.